# Regex return false don't know why

Tags: javascript, regex

when I put dot that return false I need a decimal regex which return true when I put dot

```
let pattern = /^\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$/;

console.log(pattern.test('9.')) return false

console.log(pattern.test('9.9')) return true
```

Requirement

0.0 true

9 true

9. true

9.88 true

9.999 false

Comment: `\.\d{1,2}` only allows 1 or 2 digits after the dot.

Comment: yes I need only two digit after the dot but when user enter 9. also I need to return true but It return false don't know why? I am new to regex

Comment: `9.` has 0 digits after the dot. You only allow 1 or 2. Not 0, not 3.

Comment: can you please share regex

Comment: You already accepted an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems from your question that you want to *reject* any decimal input having three or more numbers to the right of the decimal place.  If so, then use:

```js
var inputs = ["0.0", "9", "9.", "9.88", "9.999", "123.45", "k.kk"];
for (var i=0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    var result = /^\d{1,2}(?:\.(?:\d{1,2})?)?$/.test(inputs[i]);
    console.log(inputs[i] + ": " + (result ? "VALID" : "INVALID"));
}
```

Comment: console.log(!/^\d+\.\d{3,}$/.test('k.kk')) return true for that

Comment: I assumed that you knew you only had to check number inputs.  I have updated my answer above.

Comment: also I want before dot only two numbers are valid

Answer (score 0):

you should write {0,2}  instead of {1,2}

```js
let pattern = /^\d{0,2}(\.\d{0,2})?$/;

console.log(pattern.test('9.'));

console.log(pattern.test('9.9'));

console.log(pattern.test('b'));

console.log(pattern.test('21.2'));

console.log(pattern.test('212.2'));
```